# LWC Copy Element in Iterated List of Record-Edit Input

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have an LWC that creates an "array of objects" (Representing `Case` records in this case) and displays them using `iterator`:

**Parent:**

```
<template>
   <template iterator:it={cases}> 
       <c-caseform case={it.value} index={it.value.index} oncasechange={handleUpdate}></c-caseform>
   </template> 
</template>
```

**Parent Controller:**

```
export default class CaseForm extends LightningElement {
   @track cases 

   handleUpdate(event){ 
       // find the index
       let updatedCase = { ...this.cases[event.detail.index] }
       // update the value 
       updatedCase[event.detail.fieldname] = event.detail.value
       // reassign
       this.cases[event.detail.index] == { ...updatedCase };
   }

   handleCopyCase(event){ 
       // trying to insert a "copy" of the element into the next element in the array after the index of the clone'd case
   }
}
```

**Child:**

```
<template>
   <lighting-record-edit-form
        object-api-name="Case">
        onchange={handleCaseFieldChange}
        // ...
   <lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

**Child Controller:**

```
export default class CaseForm extends LightningElement {
  @api index
  handleCaseFieldChange(event) {
    let changeEvent = new CustomEvent('casechange', { detail: { fieldname: event.target.fieldName, value: event.target.value, index: this.index
    this.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
  }

}
```

From here I "update the value in the parent array of cases so that I can "Clone" them later - however when I initiate a new `<c-caseform>` the `lightning-record-edit-form` event fires it's `onChange` event repeatedly for each assigned value after initiated.

Is there a better way to "copy" the record in the parent controller?

Comment: why not copy the latest value once you click the clone button by traversing through the `lightning-record-edit-form`?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal - could I do that like a return value from API method on the form?